# NESTED table in DML subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle12c

Using Oracle 12c EE, how can I use PL/SQL package types in DML subqueries without raising the exception "ORA-00902: invalid datatype"?

### Sample Schema

```
--PL/SQL package types.
create or replace package test_pkg as
    TYPE type_record IS RECORD(
        column1        NUMBER,
        column2        NUMBER,
        column3        NUMBER);

    TYPE type_table IS TABLE OF type_record;
end;
/

--For comparison, the same types but as SQL objects.
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE type_record IS OBJECT(
    column1        NUMBER,
    column2        NUMBER,
    column3        NUMBER);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE type_table IS TABLE OF type_record;

--Table for testing DML.
create table tableX(a number);
```

### PL/SQL Types in SQL SELECT  - WORKS

The conversion from the PL/SQL types to SQL works fine for SELECTS. The below code runs fine:

```
declare
    vt test_pkg.type_table;
    v_count number;
begin
    select count(*)
    into v_count
    from dual
    where not exists(select column1 from table(vt));
end;
/
```

### PL/SQL Types in SQL UPDATE - FAILS

But using the same types and subquery in a DML statement raises the exception: "ORA-00902: invalid datatype/ORA-06512: at line 4".

```
declare
    vt test_pkg.type_table;
begin
    update tableX set a = 1
    where not exists (select column1 from table(vt));
end;
/
```

### SQL Types in SQL UPDATE - WORKS

For comparison, using SQL objects in subqueries works fine in DML:

```
declare
    vt type_table;
begin
    update tableX set a = 1
    where not exists (select column1 from table(vt));
end;
/
```

Creating SQL objects for every query is a workaround, but that would create a lot of unnecessary schema objects. Is there a way to make PL/SQL package types work in DML subqueries?

Comment: *" i need to stop using types delcared in db"* Why? What's the driver for not using SQL types?

Comment: company requirements. Keeping the code clean.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that is a matter of opinion as I use db level types because (imho) that is what keeps the code clean. But that's just a different way of looking at it.  However, what your looking for, at least in this case, is not that difficult. You are already creating a package which uses these definitions. You can just move the definitions into the package spec. Then there will be little or no code changes needed. Also these definitions can still be used outside of the package itself.

```
create or replace package pkg_t1 as  
   type type_record is record(
      column1        number,
      column2        number,
      column3        number);

   type type_table is table of type_record;

   function build_type_records(rows_to_build in integer) 
     return type_table;

   function build_pipe_records(rows_to_build in integer) 
     return type_table 
     pipelined;    

end pkg_t1;
/

create or replace package body pkg_t1 as

   function build_type_records(rows_to_build in integer) 
   return  type_table 
   is  
      v_type type_table := type_table();
   begin 
      for i in 1 .. rows_to_build 
      loop 
         v_type.extend;      
         v_type(i).column1 := trunc(dbms_random.value(1,100)); 
         v_type(i).column2 := trunc(dbms_random.value(100,500));
         v_type(i).column3 := dbms_random.value();
      end loop ;

     return  v_type;
   end build_type_records; 

  function build_pipe_records(rows_to_build in integer) 
    return type_table 
    pipelined 
  is
    v_rec type_table;
  begin
    v_rec:= build_type_records(rows_to_build); 
    for i in 1 .. v_rec.count
    loop
      pipe row (v_rec(i));
    end loop; 
  end build_pipe_records;

end pkg_t1;
/ 

declare 
  tt pkg_t1.type_table; 
  num_of_rows integer := &Number_of_rows;
begin
  tt := pkg_t1.build_type_records( num_of_rows );
  for i in 1 .. tt.count
  loop
      dbms_output.put_line( 'Result: '
                            || 'Column1==>' || tt(i).column1 || ', ' 
                            || 'Column2==>' || tt(i).column2 || ', '
                            || 'Column3==>' || tt(i).column3
                          ) ; 
  end loop; 
end ; 
/

select * from table(pkg_t1.build_pipe_records(&Rows_Desirded));
```

Comment: I don't think this directly answers the question. (The ideas may help the original poster, but I don't think they address the weird behavior at the root of their problem.)

Comment: As the question stands now I would agree. But as it is now is not what was a few days ago. The weird behavior was not the issue at that time or even present.